# Hide field from DisplayFrom with checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class that has a property `int Id` and the others are `bool`.
The class `CheckBoxes` is a foreign key in another table

I use these to display checkboxes using the HtmlHelper `CheckBoxFor`. After the checkboxes are filled and the form is saved, the data is saved in the database.

Now, I want to display these in another view.

So, I use:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    /...
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CheckBoxes)
        </td>
    /...
```

The checkboxes are displayed correctly but the Id field is also displayed. And it looks something like this:

```
Id //hide this 
1 //and this
Checkbox1
[✔] 
Checkbox2
...
```

How can I hide the `Id` field from being shown

Comment: How does it looks ? What is the output Html and what is the desired one ?

Comment: Oops i forgot to add that.  Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing, but you can try using attribute `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` on the `Id` field to exclude it from the auto-generation (this FAQ looks kind of related to what you are asking):

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

To get a better answer I think you should post the code.